# Proof of Poisson Thinning

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am not quite convinced by the proof of Poisson Thinning given in Durrett probability and example Theorem 3.7.4.

[image]

It says that the independent increment of $N(t)$ implies the independent increment of $N_1(t)$ and $N_2(t)$. However, I cannot come up with a rigorous justification for this step. Intuitively it seems to be very reasonable, however, I believe the underline sigma-algebra of $N_1(t)$ and $N_2(t)$ is strictly larger than the one generated by $N(t)$ since we have added more information. Are there any kind of argument to fill this gap?

Thanks in advance.

$\textbf{Edited:}$

I might know why this is true. Define $Y_i$ are i.i.d Bernulli random variables which are independent of $N(t)$, and then

$N_1(t_i)=Y_1+\cdots+Y_{N(t_i)}$. Then we can rewrite these events as:

$(N_1(t_i)-N_1(t_{i-1})=k, N_2(t_i)-N_2(t_{i-1})=m)=(N(t_i)-N(t_{i-1})=k+m, Y_1+\cdots+Y_{k+m}=k)$. Because all of these are independent, so we can factorize the product.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your book is claiming. Define $\Delta_i(t, s)=N_i(t)-N_i(s)$. Are we saying that $\Delta_1(t, s)$ and $\Delta_2(t, s)$ are independent, or are we saying that the pairs $(\Delta_1(t_3, t_2),\Delta_2(t_3, t_2))$ and $(\Delta_1(t_2,t_1),\Delta_2(t_2,t_1))$ are independent for $t_1<t_2<t_3$?

Comment: @JackM Sorry for ambiguity. Yes, it claims that all of these pairs $(N_1(t_{i})-N_1(t_{i-1}), N_2(t_{i})-N_2(t_{i-1}))$ are independent for all $t_1<t_2<\cdots$

Comment: Is a formal definition of $N_i$ given? From the example I can gather what it's meant to represent, but depending on what formalization is used there could be different ways of proving independence.

Comment: @JackM The text defines $N(t)$ as a family of random variable satisfying $N(t_i)-N(t_{i-1})$ are independent and $N(t_i)-N(t_{i-1})$ follows Poisson($\lambda (t_i-t_{i-1}))$ distribution... It also gives a concrete example as the stopping time of sum of exponential variables. In this case, I feel like it adopts the axiomatic one.

Comment: That's $N$ - what about $N_i$?

Comment: @JackM hh thanks for pointing out. I think I have figured out why this is true. I have added it in the edited part.